# How to Prevent PostBack Event Handler from Firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom class (ServerSideValidator.vb) that validates user input on server side (it doesn't use any of the .NET built in validators, therefore Page.Validate() is not an option for me). I am calling the Validate() method on page.IsPostback event and the class performs without any problem

My issue is, when validation fails (returns false), I want to stop the postback event handler from firing, but load the page along with all the controls and user-input values in them. If I do, Response.End(), the page comes up blank. I can programmatically instruct the page to go to the previous page (original form before postback), but it loses all user-inputs.

I thought of creating a global boolean variable in the page code behind file and check the value before performing any postback method, but this approach takes away from my plan to provide all functionalities inside the class itself. The page object is being referenced to ServerSideValidator.

Seems like all the postback related properties/variables I come across inside Page class are 'Readonly' and I can't assign value(s) to control/prevent postback event from firing.

Any idiea on how I can accomplish this? Please let me know if you need further details

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to post back to the same page every time and do your validation there, specifically on the page load event.  If the validation fails, you're already on the correct page and don't have to go to a previous page.  If the validation succeeds, then you can redirect to another page if you wish, in which case you probably don't need any data.

**Edit:**  This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I have a feeling it will do what you want while fitting into the existing ASP.NET validation design.  See http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=197 and https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx

Basically, you create a custom class just like you have now, but inherit from BaseValidator.  To follow your design, you can create an enum called ValidationType which has Alphabetic, Alphanumeric, etc.  In your custom class, create a property called ValidationType that uses the ValidationType enum.  Of course you have to add all the validation logic.  Then in your aspx page, you can add your custom validator to the page and set ValidationType="Alphabetic", etc. with full IntelliSense support.

Since you use BaseValidator, all the regular validation techniques will work including Page.Validate(), Page.IsValid, etc.  You can even create client-side validation JavaScript if you wish.

Having said this, someone has probably already done most of this for you.

Comment: It is posting back to the same page. for example I have SAVE button on Default.aspx page. When user clicks the button, on Page_Load I am coding 
if Page.IsPostBack Then
  Dim ssv As New ServerSideValidator()
  ssv.AddValidation(txtName, 'alphabetic')
  ssv.AddValidation(txtDescription, 'alphanumeric')
  If Not ssv.Validate() Then
    '' I am looking for a code block here that will bypass the 
    '' SAVE button event handler. I still want the page to finish 
    '' loading and retain all the user inputs
  End If
End If

Comment: It is posting back to the same page. for example I have SAVE button on Default.aspx page. When user clicks the button, on Page_Load I am coding <br/>If Page.IsPostBack Then <br/>Dim ssv As New ServerSideValidator() <br/>ssv.AddValidation(txtName, 'alphabetic') <br/>ssv.AddValidation(txtDescription, 'alphanumeric') <br/>If Not ssv.Validate() Then <br/>'' I am looking for a code block here that will bypass the <br/>'' SAVE button event handler. I still want the page to finish <br/>'' loading and retain all the user inputs <br/>End If <br/>End If

Comment: When I mentioned going back to the Previous Page. I simply did a javascript history.go(-1). That way, it loaded the default.aspx as a fresh load (missing all user inputs)

Comment: Thanks for the response Nelson.

Comment: I see...  In that case when you do the validation you have to save the result to use later.  You can simply create a bool variable in your class to hold it.  Typically, you use the built-in validators or create your own custom validator.  The page takes care of validating everything after the page load (or you can force with Page.Validate()).  Afterwards you have Page.IsValid to check it and stop the "save" button.  In your case you would have the this.IsValid (or similar) variable.

Comment: Any reason why your class can't be a custom validator?  Then you can use the built-in functionality.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I wanted to build a class with all kinds of common validations and make it re-usable for all projects. I could use CustomValidator, but from coding standpoint the class I built offered more flexibility & less coding. 

After reading your response, I decided to try Page.Validate by adding a asp:TextBox and a asp:RequiredFieldValidator pointing to the TextBox. What I realized is, even when validation fails with built-in asp.net controls, the page still goes through PostBack Event handler. My assumption was, if Page.IsValid=False, it skips eventhandler.

Comment: So, with this new finding I have decided to do the following - when validation fails in my custom class, I'll call a small function that will dynamically add an asp.net control and an asp.net validator. I'll ensure that the control has a value to cause the validation to fail. Then call Page.Validate. That way, I won't have to go with a global variable. I'll still have to implement If Page.IsValid on all postback eventhandlers, but there is no way avoiding it as it is required with built in functionalities as well. Thanks again Nelson.

Comment: On a second thought, it might pay off to look at BaseValidator more closely since I am planning to create clientside javascript validator too. Thanks.

Comment: The event handler will still fire.  What if you wanted to run some code on the Save click event even if validation failed (maybe some logging, etc.)?  If the event is skipped, you would never know that Save was clicked.  I honestly have never used BaseValidator so I don't know how much code is required, but it does seem that even if you have to write extra code in your validator class you will simplify the use of it later.  You put in extra time once and then save time every time you use it.